# double overflow in aspnet mvc form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

i have the following snippet in a form, where `model.maxValue` is of type `double`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Max Value:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.maxValue, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "a message" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.maxValue)
</div>
```

When the form is submitted with a really large value, say 100000000000000000000, the server will throw the following exception:

```
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

This doesn't happen when the field is of type `int`. (EDIT: when an out-of-range number is put inside an input box that takes `int`, an "invalid number" message will be displayed; no exception occurs.) Why and how to fix this error? (it's strange that it says Int32 when the type is double.) Thanks!

Comment: Probably somewhere in your controller code you implicitly convert the double to an Int

Comment: Int32 Size is  10 digit (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647) only, your value is 20 digit

Comment: can you provide some controller code?